# Error in setting headers in axios and react

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have tried many of the stack overflow solution but I am unable to solve this problem

My code is below

helper/axios.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URI,
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {},
});

export default instance;
```

App.js

```
import axios from "./helper/axios";
 
const { user } = useAppSelector((state) => state);

axios.interceptors.request.use((config: any) => {
    if (user.isLoggedIn) {
      config.headers.authorization = user.accessToken;
      config.headers["x-refresh"] = user.refreshToken;
      console.log(config);
    }
    return config;
  });
```

[Image of console]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWAIb.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try importing your `store` directly inside the file.

I don't thing `useSelector` can be called outside the Functional Component.

Example,

```jsx
import axios from "./helper/axios";
import store from "./your_path_to_store_file"

axios.interceptors.request.use((config: any) => {
    const { user } = store.getState();
    if (user.isLoggedIn) {
      config.headers.authorization = user.accessToken;
      config.headers["x-refresh"] = user.refreshToken;
      console.log(config);
    }
    return config;
});
```

By doing so, we might get the latest value from the store.

Comment: I tried that . But the following error occur "React Hook "useAppSelector" cannot be called inside a callback"

Comment: Edit the answer. Try it now.